# How to limit number of items in Recycler View?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to show only 5 items in recycler view though I have many items available in database. One method I know is to set the number in  setCount() method. Is there any other way to limit the number?

Below is my code:

**HomeFragment.java**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

FragmentHomeBinding fragmentHomeBinding;
OfferAdapter offerAdapter;
List<Offer> offerList = new ArrayList<>();

public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    fragmentHomeBinding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false);
    
    fragmentHomeBinding.offerRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    offerAdapter = new OfferAdapter(offerList,getActivity());
    fragmentHomeBinding.offerRecycler.setAdapter(offerAdapter);
    
    return fragmentHomeBinding.getRoot();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    fragmentHomeBinding = null;
  }
}
```

**OfferAdapter.java**

```
public class OfferAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OfferAdapter.ViewHolder> {

List<Offer> offerList;
Context context;

public OfferAdapter(List<Offer> offerList, Context context) {
    this.offerList = offerList;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.offer__row,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Offer model = offerList.get(position);
    Glide.with(context).load(model.getOffer_image()).into(holder.offerImg);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return offerList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView offerImg;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        offerImg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.offerImg);
      }
   }
}
```

How can I achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 2):

Just add `LIMIT 5` to the SQL query... while you apparently don't populate anything at all.

Limiting the presentation layer is in every case the wrong approach.

Comment: while i don't see a valid usage for what OP is trying to achieve, i agree that this shouldn't be handled by the presentation, this is the best way of achieving it without hacking on the other layers

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    int size=5;//your fixed size
    if(size<offerList.size()){
       return offerList.size();
    }else{
        return size;
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if it may be working, it definitely wouldn't survive a code review. This would still load all records and use memory for no good reason... and one could not use if for endless pagination either.

Comment: @MartinZeitler, I think this is what he wants, your answer best fits if he uses a local DB, but if he is getting a list from API, then this answer will do the work for him.

Comment: Even with a paged API, one still may have the option to pass a page-size... using the Adapter is still a tad better than limiting it in the `RecyclerView`. The optimum (while possible) is to limit the data-source already.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Well, that would be a better approach.

Comment: When only one has a chance, which is not always the case.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Yes, Following Best Practices makes it easier to maintain software.

Answer (score 0):

In your `OfferAdapter` class declare `size` variable like below:

```
List<Offer> offerList;
Context context;
int size = 5;
```

Then in the `OfferAdapter` class only, in the `getCount()`, return `size` like below:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    // Checks if the the number of items in the database is more than 5 or not

    if(size > offerList.size()){
        // The number of items is less than 5 return the original number of items
       return offerList.size();

    } else {
        // The number of items is more than 5, display only 5 items so return 5
        return size;
    }
}
```

And you'll get your desired output.